# eCharts how to set specific xAxis for specific series data

Tags: javascript, echarts

I have the following code:

```
option = {
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
  },
  yAxis: {},
  series: [
    {
      type: 'line',
      encode: {
        x: 0,
        y: 2
      }
    }
  ],
  dataset : {
    source: [[100, 50, 400], [200, 50, 300], [300, 100, 200]]
  }
};
```

Currently it looks like:

[Lina chart with visible axis to change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50Ay1.png)

In x axis I have the following values: 100, 200, 300 - as it is visible in the image.
Instead of having values (100, 200, 300) for x axis I want to have values for first position from dataset.source : 50, 50, 100

How to do it?